# Label a longtblr row and reference a specific column

Tags: tabularray, nameref, longtblr

I am trying to start with an example from [Reference table row in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356817/168506) to create a label for a row, but I have not had any luck getting that to work in a `longtblr` environment. The code I have so far is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{rowcntr}[table]
\renewcommand{\therowcntr}{\thetable.\arabic{rowcntr}}
\NewColumnType{N}[1][]{>{\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}c}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tblr}{\setcounter{rowcntr}{0}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Table 1},
  label = {tblr:long-table-1},
  ]{
    colspec = {N[3]|X[5]},
    width = \linewidth,
    rowhead = 1,
    rowfoot = 1,
    row{even} = {azure9},
    row{1,Z} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white}
  }
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
  \label{row:long-table-1-a} & Ipsum \\
  \label{row:long-table-1-b} & Ipsum \\
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
\end{longtblr}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Table 2},
  label = {tblr:long-table-2},
  ]{
    colspec = {N[3]|X[5]},
    width = \linewidth,
    rowhead = 1,
    rowfoot = 1,
    row{even} = {azure9},
    row{1,Z} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white}
  }
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
  \label{row:long-table-2-a} & Ipsum \\
  \label{row:long-table-2-b} & Ipsum \\
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image: repro]

There are several problems, the numbering is off, the index is included in the headers

- The (wrong) numbering is included in the header and footer.
- The row indexing is off, it starts at 2 and jumps by 2.
- The header in the first table has the wrong height.
- The width of the tables is inconsistent.

What I really want is to omit the number/index column and use a `\nameref` against the value of the second column, so that each time I reference the label, I pull in the corresponding cell value. With this approach, I can instrument any bad references (i.e., when someone updates the table and breaks the references).

I found [reference to a label linked with a longtable row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54939/168506) as a possible alternative approach, but this requires duplicating the actual cell value everywhere in the document.

I would be grateful for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad numbering is due to the fact that counters in `tblr`s don't work properly without loading the `tblr` library `counter` (`tabularray` manual, §5.3). For me this also fixed the overall table widths and the extra height in the first row of the first table.

```
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
```

The inconsistent width is because you've based the `N` column type off of `c`, which doesn't support width coefficients like `X` does. Disregarding the other issues for the moment, you could fix this by changing your column definition to:

```
\NewColumnType{N}[1][]{>{\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}X[#1]}
```

Here I've replaced `c` with `X[#1]`. `#1` gets filled in with the optional argument to `N`. Without it, you effectively get `X[1]` no matter what argument you give to `N`.

The remaining, more difficult issue is the fact that your header and footer are numbered (and still wrongly at this point). I think what's going on here is a confusion between the older style column types from `array` and the new syntax introduced by `tabularray`. When you do `row{1,Z} = {c,...}`, `c` is not a column type that will replace the column type you've already assigned with `colspec` above; it's a value for key `halign` (see `tabularray` manual §2.4--5). Furthermore, even adding `preto={}`, the `tabularray` equivalent of `>{}` to this option set won't work, because you're modifying the definition of the *row* and not the *column*.

My recommendation would be to drop the NewColumnType and instead specify the numbering as a property of only the cell range you want numbered. Your table specification would then look like this:

```
colspec = {X[3]|X[5]},
width = \linewidth,
rowhead = 1,
rowfoot = 1,
row{even} = {azure9},
row{1,Z} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white},
cell{2-Y}{1} = {preto={\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}},
```

If you want to avoid having to copy the same definition for multiple tables, you can use \NewTblrEnviron to make a new table type:

```
\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr}
\SetTblrOuter[mytblr]{long}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{
  colspec = {X[3]|X[5]},
  width = \linewidth,
  rowhead = 1,
  rowfoot = 1,
  row{even} = {azure9},
  row{1,Z} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white},
  cell{2-Y}{1} = {preto={\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}},
}
```

Lastly, you don't need `\AtBeginEnvironment{tblr}{\setcounter{rowcntr}{0}}` because `[table]` in `\newcounter{rowcntr}[table]` already does that. You also don't need `array` or `makecell` because you're using `tabularray`.

Without further ado, here's my version of your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{float} &not relevant for longtblr
\usepackage{nameref}
%\usepackage{setspace} %not used here
\usepackage{tabularray}
  \UseTblrLibrary{counter}
%\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} %not used here
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{rowcntr}[table]
\renewcommand{\therowcntr}{\thetable.\arabic{rowcntr}}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr}
\SetTblrOuter[mytblr]{long}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{
  colspec = {X[3]|X[5]},
  width = \linewidth,
  rowhead = 1,
  rowfoot = 1,
  row{even} = {azure9},
  row{1,Z} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white},
  cell{2-Y}{1} = {preto={\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytblr}[
  caption = {Long Table 1},
  label = {tblr:long-table-1},
  ]{}
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
  \label{row:long-table-1-a} & Ipsum \\
  \label{row:long-table-1-b} & Ipsum \\
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
\end{mytblr}

\begin{mytblr}[
  caption = {Long Table 2},
  label = {tblr:long-table-2},
  ]{}
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
  \label{row:long-table-2-a} & Ipsum \\
  \label{row:long-table-2-b} & Ipsum \\
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
\end{mytblr}

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT in response to your comment:

It's odd that the row numbering wouldn't work without defining a new `tabularray` environment. This code works as intended for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{tabularray}
  \UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{rowcntr}[table]
\renewcommand{\therowcntr}{\thetable.\arabic{rowcntr}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Table 1},
  label = {tblr:long-table-1},
  ]{
    colspec = {X[3]|X[5]},
    width = \linewidth,
    rowhead = 1,
    rowfoot = 1,
    row{even} = {azure9},
    row{1,Z} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white},
    cell{2-Y}{1} = {preto={\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}},
  }
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
  \label{row:long-table-1-a} & Ipsum \\
  \label{row:long-table-1-b} & Ipsum \\
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
\end{longtblr}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Table 2},
  label = {tblr:long-table-2},
  ]{
    colspec = {X[3]|X[5]},
    width = \linewidth,
    rowhead = 1,
    rowfoot = 1,
    row{even} = {azure9},
    row{1,Z} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white},
    cell{2-Y}{1} = {preto={\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}},
  }
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
  \label{row:long-table-2-a} & Ipsum \\
  \label{row:long-table-2-b} & Ipsum \\
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I notice that without using the `NewTblrEnviron`, the counter does not reset between tables. For insight, how can that be fixed?

Comment: @Ritmo2k That's odd. I've added another example to my answer; see if it works for you?